# How to return a string if an integer isn't a multiple of 500?

Tags: python

Essentially I want to turn an integer `hp` into strings of squares.

- I want to add a `:green_square:` for every 500 in `hp`.
- I want to add a `:red_square:` for every missing 500 in `hp` (max hp is 10000).
- I want to add a `:yellow_square:` for a remaining value between 1-499 in `hp`.

So far I have written:

````py
    players = await getplayerdata()
    numofgreensqs = math.floor(hp/500)
    numofredsqs = math.floor((10000-hp)/500)
    yellowsq = ?
    hpmoji = str(numofgreensqs*":green_square:")+(yellowsq)+str(numofredsqs*":red_square:")```
````

So I really just need to figure out how to get the `yellowsq`

Edit:

```
   yellowsq = math.ceil((hp-(numofgreensqs*500))/500)
   hpmoji = str(numofgreensqs*":green_square:")+(yellowsq*":yellow_square:")+str(numofredsqs*":red_square:")
```

may have found a solution in the above. need to test though.

Comment: For what it's worth: `math.floor(hp / 500)` can be `hp // 500`

Comment: `numofyellowsqs = 20 - numofgreensqs - numofredsqs` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
   yellowsq = math.ceil((hp-(numofgreensqs*500))/500)
   hpmoji = str(numofgreensqs*":green_square:")+(yellowsq*":yellow_square:")+str(numofredsqs*":red_square:")
```

This seems to work!